# MS SQL Server - create unique key for user

Tags: sql-server

I have an employee table with multiple entries for the same person.
Using their SIN number you are able to determine if they are the same person.

Example:

```
Id  Name    SIN
1   John Smith  1234
2   John Smith  1234
3   Jess Jones  4321
```

I want to be able to copy everyone in this table, into a new table.
I want to create a new column (UserKey [GUID]) that is unique to the user who is in the table multiple times.
I want to use this new UserKey [GUID] instead of the SIN number.

```
Example:
Id  Name        UserKey (Guid)
1   John Smith  1234DFKJ2328LJFD
2   John Smith  1234DFKJ2328LJFD
3   Jess Jones  9543SLDFJ28EKJFF
```

I have no idea on how to approach this query. Any help would be great.

I am using MS SQL Server 2008.

Thanks.

Comment: How is this GUID supposed to be generated?  What is the point of updating the key?

Comment: Unique per person, not the row itself.  Basicly want the exact same data as the source table, but take the SIN number and transform it into a GUID.

Comment: I understand that it's per user now, but your structure doesn't make sense.  Why is a user allowed in there more than once?  Why are you updating the key from 1234 to 1234DFKJ2328LJFD, when the net effect is the same?  It seems like a lot of work for nothing.

Comment: I agree, but there is no way around it from our business side, and we don't want to use the SIN number, as it is sensitive data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just create a temp table, mapping SIN to a new GUID. Then you can join the original table with the mapping table, and create the new table from that.

```
# Create a table called #temp with the mappings SID => new GUID
SELECT SIN, newid() UserKey INTO #temp FROM (SELECT DISTINCT SIN FROM Table1) a

# ...and join that and the original table to a new table.
SELECT id, name, userkey
INTO NewTable
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN #temp t2
ON t1.SIN = t2.SIN
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/45866/5).

Comment: This works great, thanks :) How would I run this query a second time without re-adding the columns that all ready exist.  Is there a way to update existing rows while still adding any new ones?

Comment: @PsychoDUCK Somewhat more convoluted, you need to save the mapping table instead of using a temp then since otherwise there's no mapping SIN-Guid to use. Have a look at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7eeb8/1

Comment: Thanks, this will handle any new records nicely, but it doesn't look like it will handle updates. P.S.  I am actually saving the id from table1 into the new table, so that they can be mapped.  I just left it out of my question because I was trying to simplify what I needed.  My bad.  We can say that the id column in both of my tables are the same id column pulled from table1.

Comment: FYI - I did the update similar to the insert and just joined it on a shared unique key.  Thanks again :)